# Nth digit of k!

Tags: arithmetic

Is there any way to know the nth digit of k! without having to calculate the factorial?

And, for some k, when k! is prime? (disregarding the trailing zeros, and k>2)

Comment: $k!$ is never prime since $2$ is always a divisor. $2!$ is the only exception.

Comment: for all $k \ge 3$, $k!$ is divisible by $3$ (even after getting rid of the trailing zero).

Comment: Chubby, but is to ignore the trailing zeros, doesn't change?

Comment: achille, got it

Comment: but the first question, do you know something about it?

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A008905 for the leading digit. (Curiously, the sequence $4,2,2,0,0,6,6,9\ldots$ of second digits is not -- yet -- in the OEIS.)

Comment: hmmm interesting

Comment: are there sequences for third, fourth, ... digit?

Comment: @thiago Doesn't matter if you take the trailing zeroes into consideration or not. This has to do with the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.